# Como o HTTPS (SSL) funciona?

Tags: http, criptografia, ssl

Criptografia é algo fundamental na *web*, pois nos fornece privacidade e segurança. É até possível que isso seja padrão no HTTP 2.

Minha dúvida é: Como a criptografia via HTTP funciona? Creio que exista uma chave que seja única para cada conexão entre servidor e cliente, caso contrário (se a chave fosse sempre a mesma) alguém poderia interceptar a conexão facilmente. Já ouvi falar em "certificados" necessários para a coisa funcionar, mas não sei como funciona.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

O Edgar Muniz Berlinck já [deu uma visão geral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28834/215), e [a resposta do OnoSendai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28845/215) descreve o protocolo muito bem, mas gostaria de complementar com a motivação por trás desse protocolo (e fazer algumas pequenas retificações).

Quando um cliente (digamos, Alice) se conecta a um servidor (Bob) através da internet, essa conexão é indireta - Alice manda a mensagem pra Charlie, que manda pra Dave, que manda pra Mallory que manda pra Bob. Bob responde pra Mallory, que repassa pra Dave, que manda pra Charlie que manda pra Alice. Nem sempre se sabe qual o caminho exato que os pacotes vão percorrer, nem se pode garantir com certeza que todos os nós são honestos. Como garantir que a comunicação entre Alice e Bob seja **confidencial** (ninguém no meio a veja), **íntegra** (ninguém no meio a altere) e **autêntica** (na outra ponta da comunicação tem de estar Bob, e não alguém se passando por Bob)?

A criptografia - originada há séculos no meio militar, e somente popularizada no meio civil após o surgimento da internet - busca resolver esse problema: mandar mensagens seguras por um canal de comunicação inseguro. Existem dois tipos de criptografia: simétrica (os dois pares compartilham um segredo) e assimétrica (um deles possui um segredo que o outro não possui). O SSL/[TLS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) utiliza ambos: assimétrica para assegurar a autenticidade, e simétrica para a confidencialidade e integridade.

Respondendo então à sua primeira dúvida: há sim uma chave diferente a cada conexão - a simétrica, que é resultado do protocolo de "aperto de mão" (*handshake*) tal qual descrito por OnoSendai. Entretanto, o(s) par(es) de chaves assimétricas (chave pública e privada do servidor, e opcionalmente também do cliente) <del>não mudam com frequência</del>. Mas isso não é problema, pois a privada nunca é revelada, e a pública - como o próprio nome diz - não precisa ser mantida em segredo...

(**Atualização:** após uma releitura do *handshake*, percebo que há sim um par público/privado que é gerado a cada conexão e usado para transmitir a chave assimétrica. Uma "chave cifradora de chaves" - *Key Encryption Key* ou KEK. Entretanto, o par cuja chave pública está contida no certificado, esse sim não muda com frequência: sua validade típica é dois anos, e ela somente é usada para assinar, nunca pra cifrar.)

E como esse par de chaves (pública, privada) é usada para garantir a autenticidade? Em primeiro lugar, o servidor envia ao cliente sua chave pública. Eventualmente, ele **assina** algo com sua chave privada - provando ao cliente que ele é mesmo o "dono" da chave pública. Até aí tudo bem, mas como Alice pode ter certeza que a chave que ela recebeu dizendo vir de Bob veio mesmo de Bob? Aí entra um caso do ovo e da galinha:

Se Alice *já conhece* a chave pública de Bob (i.e. tem salvo no seu computador a chave de Bob associada à sua **identidade** - por exemplo, o domínio que pertence a Bob), então é tranquilo. Caso contrário, ela precisa que alguém de confiança faça intermédio nessa comunicação (como verificar a assinatura de Bob se Alice não tem nada pra comparar com ela?). Isso é feito através de um [certificado](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificado_digital). Um certificado é:

1. Uma chave pública...
2. ...associada a uma identidade (um nome)...
3. ...e o par assinado por alguém de confiança.

Há mais de uma maneira de se fazer isso - Autoridades Certificadoras (CA), Redes de Confiança ([*Web of Trust*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust)), Notários, etc. Não sei te dizer quais o protocolo SSL/TLS suporta, mas o mais comum é o uso de Autoridades Certificadoras. Elas são, grosso modo, um conjunto de empresas cuja chave pública já vem *embutida* no software que você usa. Se você estiver usando o Firefox, por exemplo, pode verificar quem são elas consultando `Ferramentas -> Opções -> Avançado -> Certificados -> Certificados (de novo) -> Autoridades`.

(Repare que a [ICP-Brasil](http://www.iti.gov.br/icp-brasil) não está nessa lista... já notou que sempre que você tenta entrar em um site seguro do Governo o browser dá um alerta de certificado inválido?)

Se você tem por exemplo um website, e quer que ele esteja disponível de forma segura para o público em geral, não há muito o que fazer a não ser pagar para uma dessas empresas para verificar sua identidade e assinar seu certificado (criar o certificado é o de menos, qualquer um pode fazer). Levando em consideração que nem todo SO ou browser reconhece toda CA. Mas se tudo o que você quer é distribuir uma aplicação para um público restrito (digamos, algo que só será acessível aos funcionários da sua empresa) você também pode criar um Certificado Raiz - usado para assinar outros certificados - e instalá-lo manualmente no browser dos usuários. Evitando assim ter que pagar por esse serviço.

(Lembrando sempre que o meio de se **distribuir** esse certificado raiz tem de ser seguro. Ovo e galinha, lembra? Você poderia levar ele à mão, num pendrive por exemplo, mas para distribuir via internet você precisaria *de novo* da ajuda de alguém em quem você já confia...)

Fechando então, após a entrega e verificação do certificado (que é um processo relativamente lento, como apontado por OnoSendai, mas só da primeira vez, quando o certificado não está na cache), é necessário assegurar a autenticidade de Alice. Isso pode ser feito [também via certificados](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/client-certificates-vs-server-certificates-what-s-difference), mas o mais comum é omitir essa etapa (posteriormente, o uso de um simples nome de usuário e senha diz ao site quem é o usuário - sem fazer parte do protocolo SSL/TLS). Após ambos estarem autenticados, usa-se criptografia simétrica - essa sim bastante rápida - para a comunicação normal.

Comment: P.S. Não quis colocar como parte da resposta, pois é mais um *rant* que uma opinião objetiva e neutra, mas sugiro a leitura [desse artigo por Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/paper-pki-ft.txt) (em inglês) para conhecer melhor "o lado oculto" por trás das CAs. Esse esquema na minha opinião é uma zona, basta um CA ter seu certificado raiz comprometido pra todos os sites do mundo ficarem vulneráveis... Espero que isso melhore um pouco no futuro, com a evolução dos protocolos HTTP e SSL/TLS.

Comment: +1 - Excelente descrição das implicações e dependências.

Comment: A CA nada mais é que um "cartório" a certificação que você compra dela nada mais é que um "carimbo" virtual no seu site de que ele é de quem diz ser mesmo. Obviamente você não precisa carimbar em cartório um memorando interno da sua empresa. Mas um site de vendas precisa ser oficialmente identificado, assim como notas fiscais precisam de um carimbo/selo oficial. Sem as CAs o comércio eletrônico ficaria muito vulnerável a sites maliciosos. Além disso a CA tem uma validade, normalmente um ano.

Comment: Se o certificado raiz de uma CA for comprometido ela simplesmente o desqualifica (e precisa enviar novos CAs para todos os seus clientes)

Comment: @jean **quando** ela descobrir que ele foi comprometido, não? Até lá, quem tiver uma cópia do mesmo poderá assinar certificados arbitrários. Meu problema não é com os *trusted third-parties* - eu concordo com você que sua presença facilita muito nossa vida (*web of trust* é um conceito interessante, mas difícil de se implementar em escala). O problema é que *qualquer* CA pode emitir certificados pra *qualquer* site - mesmo aqueles que já possuem um certificado num CA diferente. Uma alternativa interessante seria, por exemplo, o [Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_%28SSL%29)

Answer (score 29):

O protocolo é consideravelmente robusto, mas pode onerar bastante a comunicação entre cliente e servidor.

A lista de 'passos' ( e seu código em um SSL packet) para o estabelecimento de uma conexão SSL é a seguinte:

- `0x00` **Hello Request**
  Uma conexão é estabelecida pelo cliente para o servidor.
- `0x01` **Client Hello**
  O cliente se identifica (no nosso caso, o browser) e informa suas características (versões de SSL aceitas, quais protocolos e cifras são suportadas, o ID de sessão que o cliente gostaria de usar.)
- `0x02` **Server Hello**
  Caso compatível com a versão solicitada pelo cliente, o servidor responde com a versão de SSL a ser utilizada nesta sessão, o ID de sessão a ser utilizado (vazio caso o servidor escolha não suportar sessões), cifras suportadas, o método de compressão a ser utilizado e a lista de certificados aceitos.
- `0x0B` **Certificate** (quando presente)
  Em 99% dos casos a conexão SSL irá utilizar um certificado digital para autenticar a conexão. (Alguns protocolos não exigem certificados, porém são vulneráveis a ataques do tipo *man-in-the-middle*.) Neste momento o servidor envia seu certificado.
- `0x0C` **Server Key Exchange**
  Opcional, caso o servidor esteja operando sem certificado.
- `0x0D` **Certificate Request**
  Opcional, caso o cliente precise se autenticar usando um certificado.
- `0x0E` **Server Hello Done**
  Este pacote é enviado pelo servidor para indicar que a negociação de recursos (certificados, chaves, protocolos) está finalizada.
- `0x0F` **Certificate Verify**
  Caso o cliente tenha enviado um certificado para se autenticar, o servidor responderá se aceitou ou não o certificado.
- `0x10` **Client Key Exchange**
  O conteúdo desta pacote depende da escolha de algoritmo de chave pública estabelecido entre as duas partes. O *payload* pode ser uma pré-chave mestra (RSA ou DH). Se RSA, o cliente irá gerar uma chave encriptada usando a chave pública do servidor, e a enviará de volta. Essa chave encriptada é usada para desencriptar a pré-chave mestra previamente enviada. Neste momento, a conexão SSL é decladada aberta.
- `0x14` **Finished**
  O primeiro conteúdo realmente encriptado enviado durante uma sessão SSL, o pacote `Finished` marca o momento onde dados podem ser encriptados e enviados bidirecionalmente.

Esses passos podem ser visualizados da sequinte maneira (gráfico em inglês):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir deste momento, todo o tráfego de dados é encriptado utilizando as chaves negociadas entre as duas partes.

Fontes:

[Description of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) Handshake](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257591)
[SSL Introduction with Sample Transaction and Packet Exchange - Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/secure-socket-layer-ssl/116181-technote-product-00.html)

Comment: +1 por descrever o handshake

Answer (score 17):

Eu desenvolvo aplicativos para Facebook e todos estes devem ser executados por HTTPS. Para isso eu preciso instalar um certificado no meu servidor (JBoss no caso, já que uso java).

Bem, quando as pessoas acessam meu aplicativo o meu JBoss identifica que se trata de um acesso por HTTPS e apresenta o certificado para o browser, confirmando que a url acessada de fato é a url que deveria ser acessada (Não houve nenhum tipo de ataque e coisa e tal que comprometesse sua conexão e lhe redirecionasse para outro lugar).

Quanto a criptografia, meu servidor tem duas chaves: uma chave **pública** e uma **privada**. Num primeiro acesso será instalado em seu browser uma chave pública do meu servidor, que será usada (durante o *handshake*) para cifrar as informações enviadas por você para o meu servidor - estabelecendo então uma chave compartilhada (simétrica).

Meu servidor pode usar essa chave para decifrar o conteúdo enviado por você e seu browser também poderá usá-la para decifrar informações enviadas pelo meu servidor.

Assim, eu garanto que o que eu recebo foi enviado por você e o que você receber foi enviado por mim.

Espero ter ajudado.

**Edit**

Só acrescento que para aplicações web o certificado é considerado válido se for emitido por uma organização certificadora válida e você tem que pagar por esse certificado, que tem um período de expiração. Você pode desenvolver/testar com um certificado emitido por você mesmo mas não vai servir para o ambiente de produção.

Na prática o navegador vai dar algum feedback ao usuário sobre a validade do certificado como perguntar se ele quer (se arriscar a) continuar ou mudar a cor da barra de endereço.

Você pode ir nos sites dessas organizações certificadoras para ter uma ideia de como funciona (e quanto custa) eles normalmente tem um FAQ e disponibilizam suporte, inclusive em como utilizar os certificados.

Comment: Ótima pergunta e uma boa resposta. Só acrescento que para aplicações web o certificado é considerado válido se for emitido por uma organização certificadora válida (e você tem que pagar por esse certificado). Você pode desenvolver/testar com um certificado emitido por você mesmo (mas não vai servir para o ambiente de produção). A diferença prática é que o navegador vai te dar algum feedback sobre a validade do certificado como perguntar se você quer continuar ou mudar a cor da barra de endereço

Comment: Bem lembrado @jean! Pode editar a resposta se quiser.

Comment: Atualmente há algumas empresas que fornecem certificados gratuitos e válidos, que são aceitos pela maioria dos browsers modernos. Basta uma pesquisada (boa) na web. Mas cuidado, nem sempre as CAs "famosas" ou que "a maioria conhece" são as melhores nesse quesito.

Comment: @jean A mudança na cor da barra de endereço denota um nível maior de cuidado ao se verificar a identidade do site (por isso é mais caro, destinado a empresas maiores, e só aplicável se sua empresa já tem X anos de operação). E é bom mencionar que há casos em que um certificado emitido por você mesmo é bom o bastante, veja a minha resposta pra mais detalhes. Mas concordo que - em um site destinado ao público em geral - o reconhecimento por uma Autoridade Certificadora que os principais SOs e browsers confiam é mesmo inevitável (mas nem sempre você tem que pagar pelos certificados em si).

Comment: Agora que eu li melhor: "...será instalado em seu browser uma chave pública do meu servidor, que **será usada para cifrar** as informações enviadas por você para o meu servidor" Não é bem assim: se a chave é pública, qualquer um pode cifrar com ela! E aquilo que o servidor cifra com a chave privada, qualquer um pode ler. O par público/privado permanente não é usado pra cifragem, somente para **assinatura digital**. Um segundo par é usado pra cifragem, e este gerado dinamicamente, pelo que eu entendi do "Client Key Exchange" na resposta do OnoSendai.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Talvez eu não tenha usado as terminologias corretas por não ser especialista em segurança da informação. Sinta-se a vontade para editar minha resposta para deixa-la mais rica.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Feito! Não gosto de ser pedante, mas se tratando de um assunto de segurança é importante que as informações estejam precisas. :)

Comment: Obs: A **barra** de endereço **verde** são para (empresas), e só é aplicada quando se possui um certificado SSL com ***validação estendida*** instalado em seu servidor. Os certificados mais simples (Para pessoas) é apenas um **cadeado** verde.