# Criptografia do SSL Socket Java

Tags: java, criptografia, ssl

Estou com dúvidas em relação ao SSL Socket do Java.
Vi em vários sites que a conexão do SSL Socket é criptografada, mas nenhum dos sites me dá informação de como isso funciona direito.

- Como sei que a mensagem está sendo criptografada / descriptografada?
- Como sei qual metodo está em uso para essa criptografia / descriptografia?
- Só o SSL bastaria para deixar a conexão segura?
- O metodo de criptografia usado é o que está no certificado gerado pelo Keytool?!

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Como o HTTPS (SSL) funciona?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28828/215)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Como sei que a mensagem está sendo criptografada / descriptografada ?

A ideia por trás de uma **camada** de criptografia é abstrair tudo isso do programador, se apresentando como se fosse um socket normal. Ou seja, o `SSLSocket` abriu? Então as mensagens estão sim sendo cifradas/decifradas. É simples assim! Você já viu em algum filme o personagem perguntar: "essa é uma linha segura?"; na vida real, a única resposta certa é: "se você precisa perguntar, então não é segura...".

Respondendo de forma mais precisa, a classe [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) inicia o protocolo de aperto-de-mão (*handshake*) em uma das seguintes circunstâncias:

- Explicitamente, através da chamada do método `startHandshake`;
- Implicitamente, se você tentar ler ou escrever nesse soquete;
- Implicitamente, se você chamar `getSession` e o aperto-de-mão ainda não tiver ocorrido.

Se o aperto-de-mão falhar por qualquer razão, o socket é automaticamente fechado (sem enviar nem receber nenhum dado) e nenhuma comunicação adicional é possível.

> Como sei qual metodo está em uso para essa criptografia / descriptografia ?

Usando [`SSLSocket.getSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#getSession%28%29), seguido de [`SSLSession.getCipherSuite()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getCipherSuite%28%29).

> Só o SSL bastaria para deixar a conexão segura ?

O que você chama de "segura"? O SSL/TLS provê **autenticidade** (o cliente sabe que está se comunicando com o servidor certo), **confidencialidade** (ninguém pode interceptar e ler a comunicação) e **integridade** (se alguém interceptar e tentar alterar a comunicação, isso é detectado). Note que, a menos que você exija que [o cliente também se autentique com um certificado](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setNeedClientAuth%28boolean%29), mesmo após a conexão ser estabelecida o servidor *ainda* não sabe quem o cliente é. Nesse caso, é necessário implementar a autenticação do cliente você mesmo (por exemplo, pedindo um nome de usuário e senha - o que é o mais comum).

Do ponto de vista da conexão, o uso de SSL por si só é suficiente para garantir as propriedades descritas acima. Mas claro, outros aspectos da sua aplicação ainda podem demandar segurança adicional (ex.: se o cliente for um browser, é preciso estabelecer uma chave de sessão para identificar o usuário de forma conveniente, guardando-a num cookie seguro, requisições POST precisam ser protegidas contra CSRF, etc).

> O metodo de criptografia usado é o que está no certificado gerado pelo Keytool ?

Um certificado *possui* um par de chaves que determina (ou melhor dizendo "restringe") **parte** do protocolo de criptografia. Mas outros aspectos não dependem dele. Pessoalmente, sei muito pouco sobre esses protocolos, uma vez que é um domínio bastante especializado (se deseja saber mais sobre o assunto, sugiro o [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)).

Numa [resposta a uma pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28912/215) eu explico melhor o que é um certificado e pra que ele serve. Em suma, ele é mais responsável por **identificar** os participantes da comunicação (servidor, e opcionalmente cliente) do que por proteger a sua comunicação.

Comment: É... para minha aplicação o SSL e um MD5 já resolve então hehe
Muito Obrigado cara , passei 4 horas procurando ontem estas informações, mas não encontrava de forma clara