# Permissão de pasta somente para a aplicação Android

Tags: android, file-permission

Tem como fazer com que os arquivos de uma pasta no sdcard tenha acesso somente pelo aplicativo? (algo como chown e chmod)
Não necessariamente leitura, mas impedir remoção e edição por meio de outras aplicações (ex: explorer). Desconsidere aparelhos com root

Comment: Que eu saiba não há como fazer isso. Podes é guardar teus arquivos dentro da tua aplicação Android, desde que não sejam muito grandes, e ai sim manténs o acesso somente pelo aplicativo.

Comment: Posso dar uma pesquisada, mas acho o caminho do @JorgeB mais simples.

Comment: Felipe, existe um "workaround" a ser feito que não posso dizer que funciona. Seria colocar todos os arquivos com extensão `.nomedia`, não sendo listado pelo `MediaServer`. Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442895/writing-file-on-sdcard-privately-for-application-android.

Comment: @Wakim isso até pode servir pra esconder os arquivos do `MediaServer`, mas nada impede que um *outro* aplicativo acesse esses arquivos. Ou seja, se for uma simples questão cosmética, está ok, mas se for questão de segurança, o caminho apontado por @Jorge B. é mais garantido. P.S. Não entendo nada de desenvolvimento pra Android, mas as informações [dessa página](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) não seriam relevantes? Tipo, ela descreve como cada app no dispositivo tem seu próprio *user id* e *group id*, etc.

Comment: Sim @mgibsonbr, você tem razão sim. Eu também recomendo a solução do Fernando. Essas informações são relevantes sim, reforçando a segurança nas permissões do `Internal Storage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há uma solução viável, caso você queira guardar arquivos (possivelmente grandes) no seu sdcard e ainda torná-los acessíveis exclusivamente à sua aplicação: gerar uma chave de criptografia no seu aplicativo, salvá-la dentro da própria aplicação ([como sugerido por Jorge B. nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33133/permiss%C3%A3o-de-pasta-somente-para-a-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-android#comment63263_33133)), e usá-la para cifrar/decifrar os arquivos que você quer proteger. Assim, você ao mesmo tempo se aproveita da abundância de espaço que o sdcard oferece, sem precisar gastar demais o espaço limitado que sua aplicação possui (uma chave de criptografia simétrica, como o AES, ocupa só 32 bytes).

[Essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6788018/520779) mostra meios de fazer isso. Se decidir segui-la, preste bastante atenção nos comentários do usuário owlstead - pode ser que as respostas citadas (inclusive a aceita) não sejam implementações seguras/confiáveis. Não tenho conhecimento suficiente pra opinar, mas fica aí o aviso... (ele parece saber bem do que está falando, ao contrário de mim, que sou semi-leigo no assunto)

[Essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992413/520779), por outro lado, parece cuidar bem de todos os detalhes (derivação de chave correta, modo de operação correto, tratamento de *encoding* correto), de modo que pode ser um meio viável. Ela não é específica pro Android, entretanto, mas para o Java em geral - o que a princípio não deve ser um problema. Vou transcrevê-la aqui, adaptando e comentando:

```java
/** Cria a chave para ser usada na cifragem/decifragem
 *  @param senha A senha mestra. Secreta. Ficará salva junto ao aplicativo, não precisando
 *               ser digitada pelo usuário (deve ser longa). Precisa de um meio de backup.
 *  @param sal 8 bytes aleatórios. Não necessariamente secreto. Ficará salvo junto ao
 *             aplicativo. Precisa constar no backup, junto com a senha.
 *  @returns A chave secreta. Pode-se salvar ela, ou o par senha/sal, seu critério.
 */
SecretKey obterChave(String senha, byte[] sal) {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(senha, sal, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
}

/* Para cifrar um texto, usando a chave gerada anteriormente. */
byte[][] cifrarTexto(SecretKey chave, String texto) {
    return cifrarDados(chave, texto.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Sempre o mesmo encoding
}

/* Para cifrar um arquivo binário, usando a chave gerada anteriormente. */
byte[][] cifrarDados(SecretKey chave, byte[] dados) {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, chave);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

    // O IV (Vetor de Inicialização) não é secreto, mas tem de ser diferente pra cada
    // arquivo que for cifrado. Ele é gerado automaticamente pela biblioteca.
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] cifra = cipher.doFinal(dados);

    return new byte[][] { cifra, iv }; // Ambos são necessários para decifrar! Salve-os.
}

/* Para decifrar um texto, usando a chave gerada anteriormente. */
String decifrarTexto(SecretKey chave, byte[][] cifraIV) {
    return new String(decifrarDados(chave, cifraIV), "UTF-8"); // Sempre o mesmo encoding
}

/* Para decifrar um arquivo binário, usando a chave gerada anteriormente. */
byte[] decifrarDados(SecretKey chave, byte[][] cifraIV) {
    byte[] iv = cifraIV[1];
    byte[] cifra = cifraIV[0];

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chave, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    return cipher.doFinal(cifra);
}
```

### Cuidados

É importante oferecer ao usuário um meio de fazer *backup* da chave de criptografia, ou da senha usada para derivá-la (caso use alguma). Caso contrário, se houver algum problema com o aparelho e a aplicação e/ou seus dados se perderem, o usuário perde acesso a todos os seus arquivos.

Uma maneira de fazer isso é usando uma senha/chave mestra - forte - que o usuário só tem de digitar uma vez ao instalar o aplicativo e/ou fazer backup, e a partir daí ela fica salva na área restrita do aplicativo. Uma senha mais simples ou PIN é usada no dia-a-dia, para autenticação do usuário.

### Motivação

Pense num sdcard como o que ele é: um dispositivo de armazenamento **externo**. Sendo externo, é comum e previsto que ele será desacoplado de uma máquina e acoplado na outra - de modo que ele não pode depender de nenhuma proteção oferecida pelo sistema operacional. Ele precisa se proteger por si só.

(esse é um caso análogo a você pegar um sistema com Unix/Linux, tirar o HD e colocá-lo em outro computador com um SO diferente - não há garantias de que esse SO vai honrar as permissões de acesso. Ele pode deixar qualquer usuário acessar qualquer coisa...)

A solução *default* para esse caso é a criptografia. E ela vem com todos os "*pitfalls*" e "*gotchas*" que você poderia esperar - o principal deles a importância de se fazer *backup* da chave. Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer esse *backup*, aí não dá pra dizer de forma genérica: é um balanço entre a **confidencialidade** e a **disponibilidade**. Mas seja como for que você faça, o importante é que faça!

> **Disclaimer:** não tenho experiência prática com desenvolvimento para Android, mas pelo meu entendimento [dessa referência de segurança](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) tudo me leva a crer que esse é um caminho viável. Para aparelhos sem *root*, é claro, como pedido na pergunta.

Comment: O android tem uma função que criptografa todos arquivos, evitando acesso indevido por outro aparelho caso o sdcard seja desconectado do mobile, mas esta função não é da API, é apenas uma função para usuários do Android protegerem seus arquivos (tem nas configurações), eu pesquisei sobre alguma maneira de esconder uma chave e achei o KeyChain http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html  Mas sinceramente... Não entendi nada, e não encontro praticamente nada a respeito

Comment: Creio que a resposta seja essa mesmo, mas vou esperar um pouco para ver se alguém trás mas alguma ideia

Comment: @felipe.rce O KeyChain é responsável por guardar chaves e certificados relativos à criptografia **assímétrica**. Se quiser saber um pouco mais sobre ela, veja [essa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28912/215) à pergunta "Como o HTTPS (SSL) funciona?". A menos que você tenha necessidades bastante específicas, você não precisa (nem deve) usar o KeyChain diretamente. Nesse caso, estou falando de criptografia **simétrica** - onde a mesma chave é usada pra cifrar/decifrar. Desconheço o que já tem pronto nesse sentido, e o que você tem de fazer você mesmo.

Comment: A propósito, repito que não tenho experiência com Android, mas pelo pouco que li sobre "criptografar todos os arquivos do sdcard" isso existe mesmo, mas não encontrei nenhuma informação de como fazer *backup* dessa chave de criptografia (somente li que "se você usar esse mesmo sdcard em outro aparelho ele não será reconhecido"). E, como você mesmo apontou, é uma função do aparelho como um todo, não de aplicativos específicos. Por essas razões, não me parece aplicável ao seu caso.