# Como posso adquirir HTTPS na minha aplicação web?

Tags: php, http, aplicação-web, https

Neste *link* eu aprendi como funciona o HTTPS: [StackOverFlow - Como funciona HTTPS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28828/como-o-https-ssl-funciona)

Porém eu não sei em quais aplicações eu devo utilizar, e como adquirir HTTPS,
se depende de algum *host*, linguagem de programação etc.

Para detalhar mais digo que, minha aplicação e de cobrança de inadimplentes criada com PHP, JavaScript, CSS e HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você deve usar em aplicações que você precisa proteger os dados trafegados. E só esses dados. Nunca use HTTPS para dados que não precisam ser protegidos já que há um custo extra para manipular esses dados.

Mas entenda que muita coisa precisa ser protegida. Lembre-se que dados podem ser manipulados no meio do caminho. O HTTPS ajuda evitar que eles não podem ser alterados neste processo sem que sequer seja detectado. Então não estou falando só de senhas ou número de cartão de crédito. Qualquer informação que seja inaceitável que possa ser interceptada deve ser protegida, mesmo algumas que pareçam triviais. Imagine um endereço alterado e a entrega vai pro lugar errado. Mesmo uma simples idade pode fazer você mostrar conteúdo inadequado para pessoas que não podem ter acesso àquilo. Os exemplos podem ser inúmeros.

Lembre-se da [LGPD](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2018/lei/l13709.htm).

HTTP é um protocolo de transporte dos dados tipicamente entre navegadores e servidores. A maior parte das coisas que você faz para *web* usa o HTTP. E o HTTPS é apenas uma forma "segura" de trafegar esses dados. Como você já leu na outra pergunta os dados são trafegados criptografados.

Sempre que alguém fazer fazer um *login* em um *site*, ele deveria ser criptografado para a senha digitada não ser facilmente lida se os pacotes de dados forem capturados indevidamente. Então deve usar o HTTPS.

Se existirem outros dados que devem ser protegidos, mesmo que seja só para proteger a privacidade dos envolvidos, ele deve usar o HTTPS.

Todos os navegadores e servidores HTTP como Apache e IIS sabem lidar com esse tráfego de dados criptografado pelo protocolo HTTPS.

Mas não basta só isso, você precisa de um certificado instalado no servidor para usar o protocolo corretamente. Esse certificado deve ser comprado (existem [opções gratuitas](http://www.startssl.com/) com limitações) em uma [autoridade certificadora](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoridade_de_Certifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)) que seja reconhecida pelo menos nas versões mais usadas de navegadores já que estes também devem possuir um certificado para estabelecer a comunicação. Esses detalhes já estão na outra pergunta.

Claro que para coisas internas é possível gerar seu próprio certificado. Ele pode ser usado pra tudo, mas ele não será considerado confiável fora do seu uso interno, que também precisa ser configurado para aceitar um certificado próprio.

A linguagem em si não precisa necessariamente saber lidar com o protocolo. Pelo menos não para fazer coisas triviais. Claro que em algumas situações você pode querer saber como lidar com o protocolo diretamente. Mas em geral só precisa determinar qual o protocolo a usar indicando quando é HTTPS. Portanto você não precisa entender profundamente como o protocolo funciona para fazer o básico, apenas deve ter seu servidor configurado corretamente com um certificado válido.

Lembre-se que se a página for HTTPS. Todo seu conteúdo deverá ser também.

No geral é isso, Claro que tem algumas simplificações aí. Se tiver dúvidas mais específicas, poste perguntas mais específicas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Em primeiro lugar você **não pode adquirir o HTTPS**. Se ler a resposta do **@mgibsonbr** na pergunta que refere ele explica e coloca a questão como ela é.

Se visitar o Wiki irá ler que:

> HTTPS (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure - protocolo de
>   transferência de hipertexto seguro) é uma implementação do protocolo
>   HTTP sobre uma camada adicional de segurança que utiliza o protocolo
>   SSL/TLS. Essa camada adicional permite que os dados sejam transmitidos
>   por meio de uma conexão criptografada e que se verifique a
>   autenticidade do servidor e do cliente por meio de certificados
>   digitais. A porta TCP usada por norma para o protocolo HTTPS é a 443.

Dito isto, penso que quer saber de como adquirir um certificado SSL e novamenta o remeto a uma nova leitura à mesma resposta, no entanto recomendaria contactar o seu prestador de **serviço de hosting** pelo que este terá certamente uma resposta mais de acordo com as especificações do serviço que utiliza.

A instalação no servidor e consequente utilização não é nada complicada, e mais uma vez o seu fornecedor de **hosting** irá ajuda-lo certamente. A instalação irá depender muito do sistema que utiliza mas hoje em dia já existem soluções que o permitem de uma forma bastante intuitiva de o fazer.