# Fornecedor desconhecido

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deploy, certificado-digital

Eu terminei um aplicativo na plataforma C# Windows Forms e quero publicá-lo em um site, mas o aplicativo precisa de permissão de administrador para conectar com o servidor e baixar para uma pasta do Windows. Então exportei o meu certificado de segurança, e fui abrir o certificado e deu tudo ok. Mas no momento que eu executo o aplicativo sempre fica aparecendo "Fornecedor Desconhecido" como mostra a imagem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dê mais detalhes. Só com isto não tem como saber o que está acontecendo. Pense. Você conseguiria resolver o problemas só com estas informações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como não há detalhes da instalação o problema pode ser outro mas vou dizer um dos problemas possíveis.

## Qual o propósito de um certificado?

Se uma pessoa disser que pode cuidar da sua casa, você deixa?

Provavelmente não.

Se ela apresentar uma carta qualquer dizendo que ela é confiável, você aceita?

Acho que ainda não.

Foi exatamente o que você fez.

## Como resolver?

Para resolver isto você terá que comprar um certificado confiável por todos. Um certificado emitido por alguém que pode dizer quem é você. Tem que ser uma autoridade certificadora.

O sistema operacional tem algumas autoridades certificadoras confiáveis instaladas nele. É possível instalar outras.

Então claro que é possível tornar você uma pessoa confiável mas terá que fazer isto em cada computador que for instalar a aplicação (isto pode ser feito através de redes completas em determinadas situações). Se vai publicar a aplicação em um *site*, duvido que esta seja uma solução. Em todo caso é possível oferecer uma forma das pessoas fazerem isto. Será algo complicado para quase todo mundo fazer, dificilmente elas farão mesmo que saibam como. A não ser que ela já confie em você.

O processo todo pode ser visto no [artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing). Lá tem uma lista de autoridades certificadoras. E é claro que você terá que fornecer provas de quem você é, além de pagar pelo certificado e deverá renovar anualmente.

[Essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1177552/221800) indica algumas formas para certificação grátis se o projeto for *open source*. E aparentemente as coisas mudaram desde a resposta original aqui e está mais fácil obter um certificado gratuito.

Fora isto terá que conviver com esta mensagem. É preciso deixar claro para o usuário que ele pode estar instalando algo de uma pessoa não confiável, que é risco dela aceitar e que o autor não poderá ser localizado em caso de danos (muitas pessoas não percebem que o certificado serve basicamente para isto).

[Artigo interessante sobre o assunto](https://web.archive.org/web/20190613090316/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx).

[Mais informações](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537361(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Veja também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47200/101) este assunto relacionado (mas o tipo de certificado é diferente).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).