# Utilizando o protocolo HTTPS (SSL/TSL) em um login com 2 (dois) níveis de autenticação no PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estou iniciando um projeto que irá trabalhar com informações de estoque e outros dados mais sigilosos de empresas então decidi fazer 2  (dois) níveis de login como nos sistemas de bancos.

**1ª autenticação**

- Consiste no fornecimento de e-mail e senha escolhido pelo usuário.

**2ª autenticação**

- Consiste no fornecimento de nome de usuário (login) e uma senha dada pelo próprio sistema.

Como fazer para que as páginas de login utilizem apenas HTTPS como protocolo de comunicação e transferência de dados?

Comment: O que você já fez? Qual a dificuldade? Sua pergunta está ampla demais.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe então meu problema é fazer o sistema ficar no protocolo https e fazer com que o php de a senha de login da 2ª parte

Comment: Para se certificar que o usuário vai acessar por meio de uma conexão segura, você tem que usar SSL. http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Comment: Essa pergunta tem um viés muito bom. Vou editar de acordo com seu comentário aqui, @Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. O que é HTTPS?

[[ref.]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

O HTTPS nada mais é do que a comunicação feita pela internet usando o protocolo [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) com uma conexão segura encriptada na camada de transporte com SSL.

### 2. Como usar com PHP?

[[ref.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481658/how-to-create-a-https-login-form-easily)

Você vai precisar habilitar o SSL no servidor e também rodar o  certificado SSL que você comprou (você pode dar uma olhada no [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/) que é melhor).

Com isso, você pode forçar o usuário a [utilizar o HTTPS no login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL), por meio da [configuração do `.htaccess` e da verificação do protocolo na página](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite).

### 3. Links uteis

- [*Livro do OpenSSL pro PHP*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.openssl.php)
- [*Como criar um login seguro com PHP e MySQL*](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)
- [*Como posso adquirir HTTPS na minha aplicação web?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47194/como-posso-adquirir-https-na-minha-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web)
- [*Como o HTTPS (SSL) funciona?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28828/como-o-https-ssl-funciona)
- [*"How can I force users to access my page over HTTPS instead of HTTP?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85816/how-can-i-force-users-to-access-my-page-over-https-instead-of-http)