# Função para geolocalização: http vs https

Tags: api, http, https

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que deve identificar a localização do usuário e, através de uma chamada de API (https://openweathermap.org/api), informar as condições climáticas do local. Para saber a localização, uso a função `getCurrentPosition()`. Isso funciona bem no Firefox, mas quando vou tentar com o Chrome, ele dá o seguinte erro no console:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details

Então, tento mudar para https, mas aí é a API que não funciona. Como posso resolver esse conflito?

Comment: vc tem que lançar seu aplicativo de um site https (com certificado) senão a Google não aceita a chamada.

Comment: Que erro aparece quando você diz "a API não funciona"? Pois a URL "https://openweathermap.org/api" já está em HTTPS, não entendi o porque de não funcionar, de mais detalhes dos erros por favor.

Comment: Tem comprar um certificado SSL e instalar no seu servidor. Obrigatório.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47194/como-posso-adquirir-https-na-minha-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-web?rq=1