# HTTPS Somente no cliente

Tags: aplicação-web, segurança, cliente-servidor, https, lado-do-cliente

Olá.
Estou começando agora em programação WEB, e me deparei com uma dúvida antes do site que estou desenvolvendo ir ao ar.
Como todos sabem, segurança é essencial e **extremamente importante** para qualquer sistema.
Meu sistema está hospedado na KingHost. Eles oferecem o certificado SSL da Let´s Encrypt e o instalam automaticamente no site.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Tendo o certificado SSL configurado apenas do lado cliente, todas as informações trocadas entre cliente e servidor estarão seguras? Ou seria necessário ter o certificado SSL configurado nas duas pontas?
Me desculpem pela pergunta, mas realmente estou começando com esse tipo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: É basicamente isso. *Ele cria um canal criptografado entre um servidor web e um navegador (browser) para garantir que todos os dados transmitidos sejam sigilosos e seguros.* Veja mais no site do Comodo http://www.comodobr.com/ssl_o_que_e.php

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Estava dando uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47194/como-posso-adquirir-https-na-minha-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web?rq=1  A minha dúvida é basicamente se preciso configurar o certificado também no **servidor**